# How can I pass a setting preference into a Toast

Tags: android, menu

I have set my Setting activity and my Menu (I did the old way without fragments since Im working on API 10) my Menu got 2 ítems Settings (which goes to the Activity Settings just fine) and Show Settings, this one has to show into a custom Toast the Setting Values. This is my code so far

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.config:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        OpcionesActivity.class
                ));
                return true;
            case R.id.mconfig:
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));
                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);

                TextView text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text1);

                TextView text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text2);


                // Toast...
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

And this is my custom Toast XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I Access to the setting values and what method should I use? .setText();

I have an OpcionesActivity class that looks like this:

```
public class OpcionesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}
```

And settings.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="General">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="opcion1"
            android:title="Sonido"
            android:summary="Sonido" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="opcion2"
            android:title="Usuario"
            android:summary="Nombre de usuario"
            android:dialogTitle="Nombre" />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="opcion3"
            android:title="Dificultad"
            android:summary="Dificultad"
            android:dialogTitle="Dificultad"
            android:entries="@array/d"
            android:entryValues="@array/dif" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this before you create a toast

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("your prefrens name",MODE_PRIVATE);
text.setText(preferences.getString("key","defaultValue"));
text1.setText(preferences.getString("key","defaultValue"));
text2.setText(preferences.getString("key","defaultValue"));
```

Comment: it just prints into the screen "defaultvaluedefaultvaluedefaultvalue"

Comment: did you change the key with your key?

Comment: yep I did;        ` SharedPreferences preferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("settings.xml",MODE_PRIVATE);
                text.setText(preferences.getString("opcion1","defaultValue"));
                text1.setText(preferences.getString("opcion2","defaultValue"));
                text2.setText(preferences.getString("opcion3","defaultValue")); `

Comment: this means there is no key with the name opcion1.... that is why it shows the default value check if you have committed the preference after editing it

Comment: what ever i told you was about the Shared preferences not for the kind of preference you are using